# How do i get domain url without using httpcontext.current

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i get domain url without using httpcontext.current because i am using global.asax directly there is no way to have an access current context

Comment: You should *rephrase* your question. What is purpose? What application events you've handled?

Answer (score 0):

global.asax does have access to the current context, but only in certain events. For example, it does have access in Application_BeginRequest, but it doesn't in Application_Start. So, first, I would make sure you are trying to access the URL at the right time.

Other than that the HttpApplication class, which is what global_asax contains, gives you a Request property of type HttpRequest. But again, you can only access it at the proper time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i got your problem, then you can use this javascript code to fetch the url.
rest decide the time and place for this code yourself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Server: ' + window.location.hostname);
  alert('Full path: ' + window.location.href);
  alert('Virtual path: ' + window.location.pathname);
  alert('HTTP path: ' + window.location.href.replace(window.location.pathname, ''));
</script>
```

Hope that helps